# Inserting data to somewhat complex data structure - C++

Tags: c++

I have a following data structure:

```
std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::map<std::string,std::vector<std::map<std::string,double> > > > >
```

So a map containing string as a key and as a value a list of maps, that have again string as a key and list of maps as a value.

Is there a way to insert data using one liner. (Im not aware what this technique is called.

What I mean is that in python i could do:

```
datas={"key":[{"key2":[{"key3":234}]}]}
```

I tried this:

```
ostokset.insert({ketju,{{kauppa,{{tuote,hinta}}}}});
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Here, have a `typedef`. It's good for your health :)

Comment: I pity he who has to maintain this code

Comment: The solution is to select that line and press the delete key.  There is literally no reason to ever want that.

Comment: For some reason, I really think you need a language that was meant for this, such as JSON.

Comment: This could be the C++ equivalent of being a [Three Star Programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) in C. You might want to look at the solution to "How to eat an elephant" - Don't swallow it in one piece.

Comment: _I have the following data structure_ Gross.  Everything starts to look like a `std::map` once you try one?

Comment: Just to add some depth to this, I am supposed to read in some data from text file that contains data about supermarket chains, markets that belong to these chains, supplies that are sold in markets and their prices. This is part of school assignment and as we haven't studied classes yet and I couldn't figure out any other way to store that data. Anyhow, thanks for all the comments, I got what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

**Please don't do this!** It is completely unreadable and unmaintainable.

That being said, here is the solution to your question:

```
m["key1"] = {{{"key2", {{{"key3", 234.}}}}}};
```

---

To reach this solution I basically created initializers for each type, from the innermost (easiest) to the outermost (most complex):

```
std::map<std::string, double> map_x = {{"key3", 234.}};
std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>> v_x = {map_x};
std::map<std::string,
         std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>>> map_y = {{"key2", v_x}};
std::vector<std::map<std::string,
                     std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>>>> v_y = {map_y};
```

And then started to construct the solution backwards by replacing each variable with its initialization:

```
m["key1"] = v_y;
m["key1"] = {map_y};
m["key1"] = {{{"key2", v_x}}};
m["key1"] = {{{"key2", {map_x}}}};
m["key1"] = {{{"key2", {{{"key3", 234.}}}}}};
```

Comment: Yeah I agree for the unmaintainable and unreadable, it's better to create a class with structured data over that "thing".

Comment: That may be the case, however this is a part of school assignment and we haven't studied the classes yet, so i guess this is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider an extra bracket for the std::pair inside the std::map

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::pair<std::string, double> a{"s1", 1.0};
    std::map<std::string, double> b{{"s2", 2.0}};
    std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>> c{{{"s1", 3.0}}};
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>>> d{
        {"s2", {{{"s1", 4.0}}}}};
    std::vector<
        std::map<std::string, std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>>>>
        e{{{"s2", {{{"s1", 5.0}}}}}};
    std::map<std::string,
             std::vector<std::map<std::string,
                                  std::vector<std::map<std::string, double>>>>>
        f{{"s3", {{{"s2", {{{"s1", 6.0}}}}}}}};

    printf("%f\n", b["s2"]);
    printf("%f\n", f["s3"][0]["s2"][0]["s1"]);
    return 0;
}
```

And compile with at least C++11.

Comment: Somehow this seems to fall under the ["no obvious deficiencies"](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/C._A._R._Hoare#The_Emperor%27s_Old_Clothes) category, rather than "obviously no deficiencies".